# Webassembly meaning of the 0x40 byte?

Tags: webassembly

The specification says that 0x40 is:

> a pseudo type for representing an empty block_type

Now im not entirely sure what they mean by that. Even if my block is not empty the compiler would give me 0x40 after the opcode 0x02.

Is 0x40 the analogous to "void"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's like `void`. The idea is that blocks can return a value (`i32`, `i64`, `f32`, `f64` for now), or no value at all. The types are listed under [language types](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#language-types), and [block type](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#block_type) restricts the valid types it can hold. This means that instructions can consume values that a block pushes onto the execution stack, so a block is similar to a function in that sense. You could want a block *not* to push a value onto the stack, making it `void` could therefore be useful. Or the compiler could simply not be smart enough to use that property of blocks, and instead it's using locals in some cases.

Eventually, [multi-value](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1146) will be supported which will allow functions as well as blocks to push multiple values onto the stack.

Comment: That clears things up. Again thank you very much for the great answer. Multi-value support is pretty nice and im really impressed with the progress made.